# R - how/whether to use mapply for a nested loop?

Tags: r, lapply, mapply

I'm trying to figure out how to avoid using a nested for loop or lapply to deal with a nested list. How can I tweak the mapply function below or use another base r function to extract the TRUE value I am looking for?

```
#data
l = list(a = list(2, 3, NA, 5, 1), b = list(4, 3, 3, 5, 2), c = list(5, 1, 3, 2, 4))

#how can I avoid a nested lapply
lapply(l, function(y){
  lapply(y, function(x){
    is.na(x)
  })
}) %>%
  unlist() %>%
  any()

#my attempt - I am getting the result I want but I beleive this is the incorrect implementation
mapply(function(x,y) is.na(x), l) %>%
  unlist() %>%
  any()
```

Comment: What exactly do you expect. To check if there is any NA in your list or get the index of NA's?  like `which(is.na(unlist(l)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do the trick:

```
any(is.na(unlist(l)))
```

Or do you want more?